# Converting a GCC inline assembler to delphi inline assembler

Tags: delphi, gcc

please i've this GCC inline assembler piece of code

```
int   src = 0;
dword n;
__asm(
            "sar %%cl,%%edx"
            : "=d" (n) // saves in eax,edx
            : "c" (src), "d" (n) // the inputs
            );
```

and my delphi attempt is :

```
asm
mov ecx, &src
mov edx, &n
sar cl,edx
mov eax,edx
end;
```

please is that correct ?

Comment: My advice would be to convert this code into Pascal rather than assembler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inline assembler does not work the same way in Delphi as it does in GCC. For starters, you don't have the same kind of macro and template support in Delphi, so if you want to use a declare-once general purpose assembler routine, you have to declare it as a function:

```
function ShiftArithmeticRight(aShift: Byte; aValue: LongInt): LongInt;
{$IFDEF WIN64}
asm
  sar edx,cl
  mov eax,edx
end;
{$ELSE}
{$IFDEF CPU386}
asm
  mov cl,al
  sar edx,cl
  mov eax,edx
end;
{$ELSE}
begin
  if aValue < 0 then
    Result := not (not aValue shr aShift)
  else
    Result := aValue shr aShift;
end;
{$ENDIF}
{$ENDIF}
```

In Delphi, inline assembler has to be implemented at the spot where it is used, and it is only supported in 32-bit. In such asm blocks you can use the EAX,ECX,EDX freely, plus any identifiers in the surrounding code. For instance:

```
var
  lValue: LongInt;
  lShift: Byte;
begin
  // Enter pascal code here
  asm
    mov cl,lShift
    sar lValue,cl
  end;
  // Enter pascal code here
end;
```

Comment: many thanks Henrick Hellström , i will re-start based on your valuable 
answer.
thank you

Comment: Fixed a bug in my original answer. SAR is a signed operation, so the aValue parameter should be LongInt and not LongWord.

Comment: @Alexis Thanks. That's excellent. And I would again re-iterate that a Pascal solution should really be preferred here.

Comment: Assembler might be useful in cases like this only if you want to make sure the compiler does exactly what you intend, and if it would matter if the compiler implementation of the shr operator would change between versions (such as always bitwise shr in one versions, but sar for signed types in another).

Comment: @HenrickHellström Maybe, but in my view it is much more likely that new architectures are supported for which your asm does not work. That's been my recent experience when porting to XE2 64 bit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: The function in my example will however work on new architectures, since it defaults to a pure pascal implementation. Rather, I think people who have reason to use asm now should be advised to use {$IFDEF WIN64}, {$IFDEF CPUX64} etc.

Comment: x64 is old now. What about ARM? Or some other as yet unreleased architecture. And all because you suspect that Emba might change the meaning of `shr`. That's no more likely than them changing the meaning of `+`. Only plausible rationale for asm is speed.

Comment: Actually, the UInt64 type was introduced in D7, but the arithmetic operators had bugs, so the type didn't work as expected. The only way to circumvent it (presuming you needed unsigned 64 bit integers) was by using asm. Hence, there are always corner cases when asm is the only option.

Comment: @HenrickHellström Well, we disagree. You think this is one of the corner cases. I don't.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: All I think is that Alexis asked a question about how to convert inline GCC assembler to Delphi inline assembler, and that it's not always the wrong answer to ask, even for such simple routines. What I *do* think is that it is generally best to write correct Pure Pascal code, but given the choice between a hack in Pure Pascal and assembler, the latter might give your problems when porting to a different platform target, but the former might give you problems when updating to any new Delphi version.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. You wrote a fantastic answer that covered all the bases. I upvoted you and encouraged Alexis to accept. I would just have preferred to see some guidance as to which route to go, especially for a coder who is not as proficient as you clearly are in asm. What's best for you may not be best for everyone if you follow me.

Comment: @HenrickHellström Your pure Pascal version fails when `aShift = 1` and `aValue = -5`. It returns `-2` instead of `-3`.

Comment: @HenrickHellström It's ok now.